# Creating an Inline Formset - Foreign Key Issue

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have the following 2 models that I want to use in a form set.  I'm not sure what I've got wrong

```
models.py 
class AppTradingPartnerTrp(models.Model):
    id_trp = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tpid_trp = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    name_trp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description_trp = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    idtrn_trp = models.ForeignKey('AppTransmissionTrn', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idtrn_trp', blank=True, null=True)




class AppCustomerTpRel(models.Model):
    id_rel = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idcst_rel = models.ForeignKey(AppCustomerCst, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idcst_rel')
    idtrp_rel = models.ForeignKey(AppTradingPartnerTrp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_trp')
    cust_vendor_rel = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sender_id_rel = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    old_vendor_rel = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    vendor_name_rel = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    category_rel = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

And here is where I'm trying to create the formset:

```
forms.py
CstVendorNoFormSet = inlineformset_factory(AppCustomerTpRel, AppTradingPartnerTrp, exclude=())
```

However when I do runserver I'm getting:

```
ValueError: 'AppTradingPartnerTrp' has no ForeignKey to 'AppCustomerTpRel'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got your ForeignKey relationships the wrong way round.

Side note: I noticed that in your 'AppTradingPartnerTrp' model, for the idtrn_trp FK field, you have got 'AppTransmissionTrn' as a string, I think it should be AppTransmissionTrn without the apostrophes.

Comment: It's a string only for now.  I'm working through all the Foreign Keys and tables, etc.. I'll update once I get through this piece. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have reversed the model order

```
inlineformset_factory(parent_model, model, ... )
```

Parent model is `AppTradingPartnerTrp` as it has multiple `AppCustomerTpRel` (foreign key) so

```
CstVendorNoFormSet = inlineformset_factory(AppTradingPartnerTrp, AppCustomerTpRel, exclude=())
```

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but I need to filter it on a value in `AppCustomerTpRel`.  Can you help me with that piece?